# Preventing user to leave directory in std::experimental::filesystem

Tags: c++, filesystems

Good day,

I'm creating a interface which allows other people to create files on my machine  in a certain directory.
Right now im initializing a working directory which is the only directory the users are allowed to create files.

```
namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem;
auto working_path = fs::path(getenv("HOME")) / fs::path("work");
```

Than i add the filename received to the work_path.

```
file_name = work_path / file_name;
```

Sadly this allows people to use a path like "../Documents/" to access directories they shouldnt' have access to.

Is there a smarter way  to check if the path lays outside the directory?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You could *normalize* `file_name` (after assignment, I recommend you use a new variable for the concatenated path) and make sure it's not outside of `work_path`. How to normalize a path is documented in e.g. [this `std::filesystem::path` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path).

Comment: Thank you, hoped there would be an easy way like lexically_relative or lexically_normalin  from the <filesystem> header which i sadly cant use due to my old g++ version.

Comment: Instead of programming it in, have you considered something else like [`chroot`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot) or a [docker instance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docker_(software))?

Comment: Oh there *is* a simpler way to normalize a path: [`std::filesystem::canonical`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/canonical) (or [its experimental version](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs/canonical)).

Comment: std::filesystem:canonical only works for existing files doenst it? Thats sadly not an option for me. And I dont want to run programm as a root so i could use chroot.

Answer (score 0):

First, check that the `path` to append has no [root path](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs/path/has_path); on Windows, this is a stronger statement than [`is_relative`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/is_absrel).

The obvious C++17 answer is to then apply [`lexically_normal`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/lexically_normal) and check that the result doesn’t begin with “..”.  For the TS version, you can still [iterate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs/path/begin) over the `path` and check for “..” entries, which also rejects some harmless (but questionably useful) cases.